# Typescript object with dynamic pre defined keys and custom value types for each keys

Tags: typescript

I've these kind of mulitple sub types.

```
type material = string

type weight = {
  unit: string
  value: number
}

type dimensions = {
  w: number
  h: number
  l: number
  unit: string
}

type Extra = {

}
```

In the extra type sholud includes above types names as keys with corresponding values for them. But the Extra type must be a dynamic type and can be have 1 or more from these.

For example these objects definitions should be valid

```
const Ext1: Extra = {
   material: "iron"
}

const Ext2: Extra = {
   material: "aluminium",
   dimensions: {
      w: 110,
      h: 30,
      l: 200,
      unit: "mm"
   }
}
```

and this not,

```
const Ext3: Extra = {
    material: "iron",
    unknown_key: unknown_value
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghsCAnAlnANlAvFAzsVAOwHMBuAKHNEigHUIViALYbKAb3KigFdCVgALjwEUJCtwBuGHhGGEeAWwBGyCgF8KVcNAAiKRREK4UAe2NtO3AO7ylqpBKhM7KtVyjpXDp3wHD8IjJyTUpqaABRAA8CODYABTgkYDR0AB4rKEUEZFTheERUDCdrBmYhOjKWJwATAyMTc1xhfUNjM2MNAD4tAGMm1mjgAEZhIaQ4nEzswryoACIUJHN5gBoQvoGoIYAmMZiJyw8Z3IxheZlFMRQlNY86tsbjYUybYWHhgAZ17m4XKAAzN8PNwvFAdp9gb9ePwKvNFIo7tx1OtQuR+sZBjEAftYkduCcimDFstCEiYQBrQimayEAD6FIgIHOfCpNPp0nQsjuoSAA) work for you?

Comment: @Behemoth yeah this approch is also correct. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't loop over type names, if that's what you're trying. Just assign them as properties on the `Extra` type individually

```
type Material = string

type Weight = {
  unit: string
  value: number
}

type Dimensions = {
  w: number
  h: number
  l: number
  unit: string
}

type Extra = {
  material?: Material
  weight?: Weight
  dimensions?: Dimensions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want strong define specific type for each material `Extra`, you can use more complex solution based on [Generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [Conditionals Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```typescript
interface Dimensions {
  w: number
  h: number
  l: number
  unit: string
}

interface IronExtra {
  corrosionResistent: boolean
}

interface AliminumExtra {
  price: number
}

type MaterialExtra<MaterialType> = MaterialType extends 'Aluminium' ? AliminumExtra : IronExtra 

interface Material<MaterialType extends 'Aluminium' | 'Iron'> {
  material: MaterialType
  demensions?: Dimensions
  extra: MaterialExtra<MaterialType>
}

const aluminium: Material<'Aluminium'> = {
  material: 'Aluminium',
  extra: { price: 1 }
}

const iron: Material<'Iron'> = {
  material: 'Iron',
  extra: { corrosionResistent: true }
}
```